# TypeError: EventList is not a constructor in one place, in another code works

Tags: javascript, django, frontend

Strange situation, I have django (1.8) app with feature in js. In one place everything is OK but in another I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: EventList is not a constructor
```

Code in js file:

```
var EventList=function(){};
EventList.prototype.init=function(){this.$eventslist=$(".event-list")
...
```

When I try call with `eventList = EventList();` I get message: `Uncaught TypeError: EventList is not a function`

Code in HTML file, in js code block:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/event_list.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    eventList = new EventList();
    eventList.init();
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a constructor set on the `EventList` function? I don't know what are you exactly returning from that function but you could directly call it as a function instead of instantiating it since it doesn't seem to a have a prorotype: `eventList = EventList();`

Comment: @aks please check my edit

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that it is not a constructor? Could you add the code as well?

Comment: In this place I get info that this is not constructor `eventList = new EventList();` after remove **new** I get info that EventList is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {   var
     var eventList = new EventList();
     eventList.init(); 
    });
</script>
```

Maybe you need to wait for the document is ready or you need to "var" your eventList